# How to send polygon data to wms?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, polygon, wms, map-drawing

I use OpenLayers and GeoServer. I can read kml file format from OpenLayers. And I want to edit this polygon in kml. So I want polygon data(polygon circle and center coordinate etc..) to GeoServer.

Comment: What do you mean by " I want polygon data(polygon circle and center coordinate etc..) to GeoServer."?

Comment: I want to send polygon data to GeoServer

Comment: You are reading from a local file. Do you want to upload the changes to server?

Comment: I m reading local file but I want to read and change from GeoServer.

Answer (score 3):

For that, you could publish your polygon through a WFS-T Services and loading into your Open Layers viewer, allowing you to edit it.

Look at this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html

Keep in mind to set properly the proxy.cgi